# Multiplication of simple function looks like?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, simple-functions

I was wondering what does the multiplication of two Lebesgue integrable simple functions look like.  Assume integral of a function f is defined as

[image: \sum _{{k=1}}^{n}a_{k}\mu (A_{k}),]

Comment: The product of two measurable simple functions is a measurable simple function.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbb{1}_A$ stands for the indicatrice function of the measurable set $A$, that is takes values $1$ and $0$ and is $1$ exactly on $A$, then

\begin{align}
\mathbb{1}_A \times \mathbb{1}_B = \mathbb{1}_{A\cap B}
\end{align}

Use that to check the result on simple functions: the product of two simple functions is then a simple function.